# CREATE FUNCTION for "CleanFile" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match

Tags: c#, t-sql, clr

Been scratching my head with this one for a few hours.   I've got a handful of CLR DLLs which work ok, but this most recent is giving me a few headaches.  Any insight will be helpful.

I've tried several things, such as various string lengths (including nvarchar(MAX)), plus also checked [mapping docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-ver16)

Error Message:

> CREATE FUNCTION for "CleanFile" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match.

SQL Command I'm running:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CleanFile](@filename nvarchar(500), @runmode int)
RETURNS nvarchar(500) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [sqlFileClean].[sqlFileClean].[CleanFile]
```

C# DLL:

```
//usings removed for visibility
public class sqlFileClean
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString CleanFile(
            SqlString FileName,
            SqlInt32 RunMode)
    {
        try
        {
           //Code removed here for visibility
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // return any unhandled error message
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: What is the string being returned in the try block or how is that return value defined?

Comment: Did you try `nvarchar(max)` on the return value, or only on the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made copy/paste your code into new project in VS 2019, then registered assembly (permission_set=SAFE) on MSSQL 2019 - it works fine (in try block just returned some string).

Ensure that your assembly is created from latest and successfully compiled DLL.

If no success - give more details about what you are doing in try { }

If you need to use NVARCHAR(MAX) - you have to use in C# - SqlChars type instead of SqlString.

Comment: After lots of head scratching, I did exactly what you did.

Created a brand new project, copied and pasted the code into the project, compiled and it worked.

No ideas on why this didn't work in the existing project, but thanks. My guess is that there was something behind the scenes in one of the project files which was causing the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this with same problem, I solved the issue by coping the code into a brand new project.